# Django Regex - find word position

Tags: regex, django, django-views

Example if I have this paragraph:

```
paragraph = "Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers;" +
"A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked;" + 
"If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers, +
"Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?"
```

And I have this regex string:

```
strRegex = "[[:<:]]pick.*[[:>:]]" # match pick/picked/pickled
```

How do I make it in such a way that all the word that fit the regex will be **BOLD**?

Please advice me in django view form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsitute it :

```
import re
re.sub(r"(.*)it(.*)", r"\1<b>it</b>\2", "Bold it!")
'Bold <b>it</b>!'
```